# Request Body with optional property

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have an endpoint which receives a JSON through POST request.

```
RequestMapping(value = "/app/login", method = RequestMethod.POST,
        headers = { "Content-type=application/json" })
@ResponseBody
public LoginResponse logIn(@RequestBody LoginRequest jsonRequest) {
   // code
}
```

LoginRequest:

```
public class LoginRequest {

    private String user;

    private String password;

    private String idPush;

    private Integer idDevice;

    // getters and setters

}
```

Is there anyway I can specify idDevice as optional?

If I don't send idDevice inside the json, Spring returns a 400 error.

Comment: How do we handle if the request body is a generic, like `@RequestBody SearchParam<T> jsonRequest`. 
the flag `required=false` is applied at SearchParam and not the extending class.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It seems that setting the RequestBody to optional, makes any property optional, not only the full bean.

```
public LoginResponse logIn(@RequestBody(required=false) LoginRequest jsonRequest) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have a small misconception about java.
For resolution of this problem you just have to assign a default value to your optional property like in the example below.

```
public class LoginRequest {

    private String user;

    private String password;

    private String idPush;

    private Integer idDevice = -1;

    /*
The change above will make it such that you can exclude that given property from
your JSON. As it now has a default value for cases where you do not assign it

   //getters and setters
   */
}
```